# Magento 1.9: Display out of stock products for a Store view

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock

I have this situation where I need to display out of stock products in one of my stores.

I use multistore Magento installation, so 4 stores are running under one installation.

For 3 stores I have set in Magneto not to display products which are out of stock - which is Ok (I need that)!

**Question/Issue:** 
For one store I have to make all products are shown in the frontend, but it seems like the stock option -> Display Out of Stock Products (yes or no) is configured with default config within the installation of Magento.

Does somebody know how to Display out of stock products in one of my stores?

Thanks

Comment: Under each website in the system configuration you should be able to uncheck use default and change the value acoording to your preference if it doesnt show in store view i would recommend looking in website view

Comment: Thank you Dava, I have tried to follow your instruction, but unfortunate "store view" or "website view" doesn't show the option "Display Out of Stock Products" to be selected in Inventory menu. 

I found this very weird.

Comment: It should be shown on store view i have just checked a v1.9 installation of magento and it is there can you please put a screenshot of your store view / edit product

Comment: thank you for your effort! Here is a link to printscreen: ***https://ibb.co/dktRY8M***! I'm not familiar how to post a print screen on stackexchange, so if I disturb any regulation I apologize in forward. Dear Dava Gordan are you able to put a screenshot of your store view, so that I can compare? Thanks

Comment: That is the system config can you look in the edit product view under that store view

Answer (score 0):

Please select the **store view** first while editing product in the admin panel. Then click on the inventory menu, here select out of stock in **Stock Availability** dropdown then uncheck the **use config setting**.

Comment: Thank you Mukesh, I have tried to follow your instruction, but unfortunate "store view" or "website view" doesn't show the option "Display Out of Stock Products" to be selected in Inventory menu. 

This option is only available through "Default Config View"!

If you are able to sent a print screen of what do you see, I would appropriate it. 

I found this very weird.

Comment: @user15151 Please check my snapshot for setting

Answer (score 0):

I found the work around solution - which works just great. The answer is available at the following link: [make magento show out of stock products for different website in multistore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399222/how-to-make-magento-show-out-of-stock-products-option-different-per-website-st)

***UPDATED***

I was wrong. Above solution I provided is not working. My bed and I apologize.

Enybody?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Out of stock setting for a store view]
Please check the settings to make product out of stock for the respective store view.

Comment: Hi Mukesh Ojha, thank you for your effort and for posting this picture! My store view has this option 1) Stock availability -> out of stock adnd 2) gty -> 0!

But, my specific store is still not showing out of stock product, and I want to show all out of stock products.

Thanks

Comment: @user15151 I need to check to why it is not showing out of stock. Can you please share your snapshot or send me the details so I will check.